# jquery: iterating through various ul's list-items?

Tags: jquery, keypress, loops

hey guys,
someone already helped me solving the following problem: i wanted to iterate with my up and down arrows through list-items. http://jsfiddle.net/zBjrS/1/
in this example i only had one UL and wanted to navigate through its list-items.

meannwhile i have multiple ul's underneath each other and want to navigate seemlessly through all of them as if there were only one UL. http://jsfiddle.net/zBjrS/2/

any idea how i could do that?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether any elements have been found, and if they have not, try using `.parent().prev().children(':first')` (or `:last` for going backwards).  See [my update to your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/zBjrS/4/);

Comment: thank you: one last addition - how can i additionally only navigate through items with a specific class. so that it iterates only through .matched items? http://jsfiddle.net/zBjrS/5/

Answer (score 0):

you could give each li an id with a number

```
<li id="item_1"></li>
<li id="item_2"></li>
```

store the number of the selected item somewhere and use it to build an id string to use as the selector